# Egit: unable to çheckout new branch

Tags: android, eclipse, git, egit

I'm trying to checkout a new branch in Eclipse using Egit but I keep getting the same message:

[image]

I tried dealing with this in any way possible. Selecting "Commit"or "Stash" only tells me that there are no changes to be stored. Selecting "Reset" only makes the error reappear after a few seconds. Other than this I pulled, cleaned and re-cloned the project a few times. I also  created the following .gitignore file:

```
*target*
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
*.class

# eclipse specific git ignore
*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
bin/**
tmp/**
tmp/**/*
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch
```

Still no luck. I really don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure bin isn't already versioned:

```
git rm --cached -r bin
```

Add bin to the .gitignore

```
bin/
```

(no need for `/**`)

And finally, try again to checkout the other branch.